# Insert data from server response to grid

Tags: url, extjs, response

Hello i am have

```
 proxy: {
                            type: 'ajax',
                            url: '/book/list?filter=',
                            reader: {
                                type: 'json',
                                root: 'data',
                                successProperty: 'success'
                            }
```

and then i have response from server

```
data":[{"id":1,"book":"Now","author":"q"}]}
```

and this date i am want insert in grid with next columns: Id, Book, Author

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Its Simple.For more details you can check out [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel)

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
title: 'RecordsGrid',
store: yourStore,//your store which contains data returned form the server
columns: [
    { text: 'Id',  dataIndex: 'id' },
    { text: 'Book', dataIndex: 'book'},
    { text: 'Author', dataIndex: 'author' }
]
});
```